# Bootstrap PHP Radio Button Display Value When Changed

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I have a form with 36 radio buttons and no labels. Right now the value of the radio button selected is captured and echoed after the user clicks the submit button.

I would like the selection to be echoed before the user clicks on submit so the user knows the value selected before they commit The value would need to be updated and echoed in real time.

This is the radio buttons code:

```
<form id="gradeForm" class="form-inline" method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
        <div id="radioButtons" >
          <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th colspan="3">-</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
<td><input class="form-check-input position-static" type="radio" name="blankRadio" id="blankRadio1" value="80" aria-label="blankRadio1"></td>
<td><input class="form-check-input position-static" type="radio" name="blankRadio" id="blankRadio2" value="82" aria-label="blankRadio2"></td>
...
...
...
<td><input class="form-check-input position-static" type="radio" name="blankRadio" id="blankRadio9" value="100" aria-label="blankRadio9"></td>
```

And it echoes this:

```
<input id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" 
type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter">

$gradeInput = $_POST['blankRadio'];

if ($gradeInput <= 39) {
    $gradeLetter = "E";
} elseif
... 
...
...
else {
    $gradeLetter = "A+";
}


    <div id="results" class="col-md-4">
      <p> Grade score:  <?php
          echo $gradeInput;
      ?> and Grade is: <?php
          echo $gradeLetter;
          ?> </p>
    </div>
```

[Form Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z7Wj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with purely PHP. You'd have to use some Javascript.

Here's an example of what you could do:

```
<td><input class="form-check-input position-static" type="radio" name="blankRadio" id="blankRadio1" value="80" aria-label="blankRadio1"></td>
<td><input class="form-check-input position-static" type="radio" name="blankRadio" id="blankRadio2" value="82" aria-label="blankRadio2"></td>
<td><input class="form-check-input position-static" type="radio" name="blankRadio" id="blankRadio9" value="100" aria-label="blankRadio9"></td>

<div id="results" class="col-md-4">

</div>

<script>
  let rows = document.querySelectorAll(".form-check-input");
  let output = document.getElementById('results');

  rows.forEach(row => {
    row.addEventListener('click', function() {
      output.textContent = this.value;
    });
  })
</script>
```

The input buttons will each receive an event listener which, when clicked, will change the text of the div with id="results" to the value of the radio button.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Worked perfectly.